# How do I find out which dlls an executable will load?

Tags: dll, executable

If I have a Windows executable, how can I find out which dlls it will load?

I'm just talking about which ones that will be loaded statically, not ones it might load dynamically with something like LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are utilities that will do this for you.

In the past I've used the MS tool (depends.exe) that came with (I think) VB.:
[VS2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20111210021011/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx)
[VS2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20130110162057/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx)
[VS2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227031953/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx)
[VS2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20171228054548/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx)
[Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160)

and there's this as well:
http://dependencywalker.com/

and probably others as well.

Comment: The "depends.exe" that's installed with Visual Studio/VB/... and the "depends.exe" that one can download from http://dependencywalker.com/ are exactly the same tool (only different versions). ;)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 76):

[dumpbin](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114095715/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) is a tool that comes with VC++.

To see what DLLs a program will import:

- Open Visual Studio
- Menu Item Tools | Visual Studio Command prompt
- cd to folder containing executable
- dumpbin /dependents whatever.exe

> ```
> Dump of file whatever.exe
>
> File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
>
>   Image has the following dependencies:
>
>     AIOUSB.DLL
>     sqlite3.dll
>     wxmsw293u_core_vc_custom.dll
>     wxbase293u_vc_custom.dll
>     KERNEL32.dll
>     ole32.dll
>     OLEAUT32.dll
>     MSVCP90.dll
>     MSVCR90.dll
> ```

To see what functions (and DLLs) it will import, use

```
C:\> dumpbin /imports whatever.exe
```

Comment: I believe it should be: dumpbin /dependents whatever.exe

Comment: /dependents only shows you the DLLs. /imports shows you functions *and* DLLs.

Comment: This is the best answer. Unfortunately this tool shows only DLLs loaded directly for the `.exe` not DLLs which the executable file depends on them indirectly.

Answer (score 23):

Open the command prompt and then type below command

**tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq netbeans.exe"**

Type instead netbeans.exe whatever name your exe file name.

Comment: i used this and its not giving me full list of dlls that its using, there are a bunch of crystalreports dlls that my exe is using but i dont see any mentioned in the list printed through that command. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this needs the application to be running

Answer (score 13):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can help you determine which .dll will be loaded.

Comment: Nice GUI program. `Dependency Walker` try to find DLLs and their hierarchical dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

Just go to the command prompt and type `tasklist /m`, you will see the list of dll files used by specific program.

Comment: Yeah, this does what you say, however, if an executable start multiple processes, you will never find out from command line which process was started by the executables, hence you will not know all the dependent dll's of the executable.

Comment: Doesn't load the paths.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Microsoft .Net:

```
foreach (AssemblyName a in Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("SAMPLE.EXE").GetReferencedAssemblies()) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(a.Name); 
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't include the reference dlls that is required from it's children.

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy tool called NDepend that will give you all DLL dependencies.

Comment: _`NDepend` is a static analysis tool for .NET managed code'_. So it works only for .Net applications.

Comment: You forgot to mention that it works as a vs extension.

Comment: @SuB a C++ version of NDepend exists: https://www.cppdepend.com/

Answer (score 1):

progfr is simple and useful:
[http://members.fortunecity.com/michaelmoser/tip11.htm]

Answer (score 1):

[Dependencies - An open-source modern Dependency Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) shows which DLLs a Windows executable will load and it works well in modern Windows 10.

It is a little less powerful than [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), but the latter may or may not work in Windows 10 as it was last updated in 2006. (Newer versions of Dependency Walker were bundled with some versions of Windows Development Kit for Windows 10, but not any more.)

Answer (score 0):

Process Explorer
Comes with SysInternals Suite 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite

Benefits: allows to explore the process that is already running (I have not found a was to attach the dependency walker to the existing process)