# Haxe compiled code doesn't run

Tags: dll, haxe, neko

I'm having trouble getting executables compiled from Haxe source to work on computers that don't have Haxe installed. The problem first appeared with a simple networking program but it seems to come up for any program at all. Even something like

```
class Test
{
    static function main()
    {
        trace("test");
    }
}
```

compiled to an exe with `haxe -main Test.hx -neko Test.n` and `nekotools boot Test.n` will run on my computer but on anything else gives a `neko.dll is missing from your computer` error. I get a similar error if I compile the haxe source to c++ or c# and run the generated exe.

I'm not sure what neko.dll is, but I don't see how it should be required for the exe to run. I feel like I must have some basic misconception! Is this intended behavior? How can I compile Haxe code so that it will run on any windows machine without installing neko?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**neko.dll** is normally located at **C:\HaxeToolkit\neko**. You may just copy and paste that next to the exe.

Generally when distributing a exe, you have to also distribute the required dlls. You can check the dll dependency with [various tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475148/how-do-i-find-out-which-dlls-an-executable-will-load). For example, using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), open the exe by it and it will list out the dlls. Right click a dll item in its menu and select properties, there you will find where it locates.