# How do I automatically find all dynamic libraries my Rust program uses (and put them into one directory)?

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

I am building a Rust application that uses the [iui crate](https://crates.io/crates/iui).

When I click the executable after doing `cargo build`, I get an error saying that the DLL isn't in the path. I did put the DLL in the path to see if it worked and it did but it opened a command window with the GUI which it doesn't do that when I run `cargo run`.

I don't know a lot about how Rust builds executables and I don't know where Rust keeps the dependencies so I would like to know how I can get all my dependencies in a single path. Having something that can grab all the dependencies for me would be nice because the dependency has other dependencies that I probably need to add and I really don't know what they are.

I plan on making an installer for my Rust application and I will need all of the dependencies for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to Rust. For Windows, you'll find the tools in this answer: [How do I find out which dlls an executable will load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475148/how-do-i-find-out-which-dlls-an-executable-will-load)

Comment: Yeah I already figured it out.