# What 3D (engine) are they using?

Tags: user-interface, 3d, reverse-engineering

I am interested in a tool that can determine (or provide useful information about) what product (e.g., component or any other stuff) has been used as part of a modern or legacy GUI application, particularly for 3D viewer?

As for example, say, Autodesk Maya, Solidworks, Comsol, etc. is running, I want to know what piece of software they have used for 3D viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check dlls used by your application to see if any of them are related to any 3D engine you know.

Try [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475148/how-do-i-find-out-which-dlls-an-executable-will-load) Stack Overflow question.